# Error when starting Server with Gephi DB

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I am (truly) a beginner. So apologies in advance.

I built a Gephi (0.8.2) DB using the Neo4j plugin, and tried to open in my Neo4j 2.0.1 and got the following message:

> Starting Neo4j Server failed: Startup failed due to preflight task [class org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformUpgradeIfNecessary]: Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"

Is it an incompatibility issue between versions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your Neo4j database to 2.0.1 first, 
i.e. start it with a 2.0.1 server and set `allow_store_upgrade=true` in `conf/neo4j.properties`

Or rebuild the plugin, I added automatic support for store upgrades.